# Number of chromatids Before S

Tags: cell-biology

Is it better to say 0 chromatids or 46 Chromatids in a human cell?

Because most of the webpages I have seen say 46 chromatids and some clarified that it is infact according to the definition 0 but 46 is more commonly used

Comment: Please add some citations to your sources.

Comment: Just as MattDmo said add some citation, the chromatids (you mean sister chromatids?) are synthesised IN the S phase so there are no chromatids before the S phase, I don't understand your confusion?